# C# - Errors with dependencies in class library

Tags: c#, dll, dependencies, class-library

So, i'm pretty new to Class Library.
I was asked to develop a C# class library that should be used by a third-party software, i first created it with .NET 6.0, everything worked fine but the third party sofwtare happened to only be compatible with .NET framework 4.X

I then created a new class library - .NET framework 4.8, refactored the code and had to add 'System.Text.Json' using NuGet because it seems that it's not part of .Net Framework 4.8 (?)
I then proceeded to test this new version using a console application -> Got errors when deserializing some Json : "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json'..." to solve this i needed to import 'System.Text.Json' to my console application too, even thought i'm only using it in the class library -> Is this a normal behavior ?

After assessing that everything was still working, i built the solution, picked up the dll in the 'Release' folder and then imported it in the third party software -> I got the same error "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json'..."

Am i missing something with C# dependencies ?

I tried to :

- Clean then build the solution again
- Tried to add the 'System.Text.Json' dll to the third party software, but i then got the same error but for another dependencie : "Could not load file or assembly System.Runtime.CompilerService.Unsafe, version=4.0.1.4'..."
  I checked my dependencies and this one is used but in version 6.0.0, so i assume i got this error because it is a dependencie of a dependencie ?

**UPDATE :** I tried some things, and found that my console app was also using .NET 6.0 instead of .NET Framework 4.8, after re-creating it, it works without me adding the 'System.Text.Json' using NuGet. So my first question is answered
I still can't figure out why it doesn't work in the third-party software.
I tried to turn the 'specific version' on 'System.Runtime.CompilerService.Unsafe'to false, but i still got the same error message

Comment: where did you put which dlls in the third party software?

Comment: It got an 'UserClass' Folder where you put all your dlls that are to be used within it, so i put everything in here (the whole content of the 'Release' Folder that was created when i built the solution)
Also i find it strange that i got this error when i used a console app to test my library